# selecting age group using dob during search

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to implement a search where the user can search for candidates above or below 18 years.

The html for the age component in the search:

```
  Age<select id ='eighteen' name="eighteen" size="1" >
  <option value="Below Eighteen">Below Eighteen</option>
  <option value="Above Eighteen">Above Eighteen</option>
  <option value="Any">Any</option>
   </select>
```

The php code:

```
$age = trim($_POST['eighteen']);    

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM p_candidate WHERE YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(`age`) >= 18");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM p_candidate WHERE YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(`age`) < 18");
if ($age =="Below Eighteen") {$dob = $query;}
if ($age == "Above Eighteen") {$dob = $query2;}



$Odata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM p_candidate WHERE(`gender` LIKE '%".$Gender."%') AND (`age` LIKE '%".$dob."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

When I run this code without filling the gender field in the search form, I do not get any results. How can I get this to work? Which part do I need to modify?

My db is in mysql and the DOB of candidates are stored in a column called age

Comment: 2 if statements ??? How can a person's age be below 18 or above 18 same time? try else if :)

Comment: What if they're exactly 18?

Comment: I have changed query2 to                                        $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM p_candidate WHERE YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(`age`) >= 18");

Comment: @HardikThaker - tried elseif but that did not work

Comment: $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM p_candidate WHERE (`gender` LIKE '%".$Gender."%') AND (`age` LIKE '%".$dob."%')") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: @user2510479 : try the above query !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I finally used - it works now

```
if ($age == "Above Eighteen") {
$Odata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM p_candidate WHERE(`gender` LIKE '%".$Gender."%') AND     (YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(`age`) >= 18)") or die(mysql_error());}

if ($age == "Below Eighteen") {
$Odata2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM p_candidate WHERE(`gender` LIKE '%".$Gender."%') AND     (YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(`age`) < 18)") or die(mysql_error());}
```

Answer (score 1):

To see if they're at least 18 years old, you can subtract 18 years from the current date and compare their birth date (which appears to be the `age` column) to that.

*18 or older*:

```
SELECT * FROM p_candidate WHERE age <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR
```

*Under 18*:

```
SELECT * FROM p_candidate WHERE age > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR
```

I'd also avoid using `LIKE` when you don't have to. If you're checking for gender `F` or for gender `M` then just say `WHERE gender = 'F'` or `WHERE gender = 'M'`. You gain nothing by over-using `LIKE`, and you risk slowing down otherwise optimizable queries.

Comment: thanks @EdGibbs but I still am not able to get the code to return values.

Comment: It may be your PHP code. In your example you're setting `$dob` to `$query` or `$query2`, but when you actually do the query (last line of your code) you're running a completely different query. If you set `$dob` to one of my queries (plus logic for the gender) and then run the `$dob` query it should work fine. Also note that you shouldn't be using the `mysql_*` family of functions because they can lead to SQL Injection - there have been many posts from coders whose sites have been hacked because they used the `mysql_*` approach, and it's a career-limiting thing to have your site hacked.

Comment: thanks @EdGibbs - I make it work finally :) I have posted the code snippets in the answers. Thank you so much for your input !!!

Comment: You're welcome, but note that your logic subtracting the years isn't quite right. Say a candidate has a birth date of `9/27/1995`. Your logic will have them as 18 years old as of today, but they won't actually be 18 for another three months. If that's close enough then no problem. If not then try my solution, which works to the day.

Answer (score 1):

Force the a default value for your select so the field will be always filled with something.
Like this:

```
 Age<select id ='eighteen' name="eighteen" size="1" >
  <option value="Below Eighteen">Below Eighteen</option>
  <option value="Above Eighteen">Above Eighteen</option>
  <option value="Any" selected>Any</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: that is  a very valuable suggestion @GuiGreg